# Text Input Validation

Tags: jquery, html, css, validation

http://jsfiddle.net/ZKsjr/
I am working with this script which is able to validate an input field with style correctly but I am trying to implement a new feature so that it resets to the original value name (first name) if incorrect information has been used (var reg = /^[a-z ,.'-]+$/i;) but this needs to happen after they've finished entering input (blur), would you know how to fix that?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo</title>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js'></script>       
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">   

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
function isfname(text){
    var reg = /^[a-z ,.'-]+$/i;
    return reg.test(text);
}

$(".fname").keyup(function(e) {
    var $test = $(this);
    if (isfname($test.val())) {
        $test.css("border-color", "rgb(140, 202, 165)");
        $test.css("background-color", "rgb(140, 202, 165)");
        $test.css("color", "black");

    }else{
        $test.css("background-color", "rgb(198, 95, 88)");
        $test.css("border-color", "rgb(198, 95, 88)");
        $test.css("color", "black");
    }
}).blur(function(e) {
    $(this).css("background-color", ""); 
    $(this).css("border-color", ""); 
    $(this).css("color", "");


});




});//]]>  

</script>


</head>

<body>

  <input type="text"id="element_2_2"  class="fname" maxlength="255" size="8" " value="First Name" 
 onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'First Name';}"
 onfocus="if (this.value == 'First Name') {this.value = '';}" required/>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes, with PHP or some other server-side script. Javascript is not suitable for validation since it can be deactivated. Check [the warning in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3602530/938236)

Comment: I won't be using javascript alone, the problem I am having is that the blur function sets the background and border color to it's default value which is great but it doesn't reset the default value if someone enters invalid data.

Comment: @Francisco Well, having client-side validation _is_ useful as long as you back it up with server-side validation. :)

Comment: thanks for tip Franisco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the field value in `.blur` and set the value of the field to `First Name`.

Like this...

```
.blur(function(e) {
    $(this).css("background-color", ""); 
    $(this).css("border-color", ""); 
    $(this).css("color", "");
    if(!isfname($(this).val()))
       $(this).val('First Name');
});
```

[**updated jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/neo108/ZKsjr/13/)

Comment: I am trying to do it after the user has clicked off the input field, what you're doing is reseting the value to first name while they are still typing.